# Run a script when cell is not empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The script sends automated mails and needs to be triggered, when a cell (e.g. A1) is no longer empty.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = 1; 

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 11);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[9]; 
    var message = row[10];
    var subject = 'Subject';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a simple if statement:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = 1; 

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 11);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    if (data[i][0] != '') { //check cell A is empty in the row the script is running for.
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[9]; 
      var message = row[10];
      var subject = 'Subject';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```